# How to prevent xticklabels from being cutoff

Tags: python, matplotlib, yaxis, x-axis

is there a way to modify a matplotlib plot to ensure that the x-axis tick labels are fully visible?

I wrote below python code to plot GPA of some students on a diagram but x-axis tick aren't seen.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10)*4
xlabel = []
for i in range(10):
    xlabel.append(f"GPA of student {i}")
plt.plot(xlabel,a)
plt.title("Plot a test diagram")
plt.xticks(xlabel,rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please attach a snapshot of the plot you're getting.

It's likely that the rotation is pushing the labels out of your plotting window and is cutting it off. try doing it without the rotation. If it works, I have a neat solution to bring the labels back in the viewing window with the rotation in tact

Comment: `plt.tight_layout()` before `plt.show()`. Additionally, the independent axis is discrete categories, so this should be a bar plot, not a line plot.

Answer (score 0):

There is an icon in your plot window that you can use it to edit your plot.

1. click on configure subplots in your plot window
2. Modify the values in the boxes to shift your plot in any direction.